# ¿Como modificar expresión regular JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una expresión regular para validar un campo de hora ej.

`var ex_ER = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/; //03:03`

Sin embargo cuando registro un valor similar a 3:3, es falso debido a que no corresponde a la expresión regular...

> Por lo que necesito es hacer una modificación a la expresión regular para que a pesar de ingresar datos como 3:3 o 03:03 pueda validarlos correctamente... Asumiendo que como especifica la expresión anterior solo se puede ingresar a partir de las 00:00 hasta las 23:59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes repetir una lógica similar a lo que hacés para las horas, pero para los minutos.
Ahora, si lo que querés es realmente validar horas, no creo que `3:3` sea un formato válido. Nunca vi un solo dígito para los minutos.

```js
var regex = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])$/;
var time1 = '03:03';
var time2 = '3:3';
var time3 = '24:00';

console.log(time1 + ' ' + regex.test(time1));
console.log(time2 + ' ' + regex.test(time2));
console.log(time3 + ' ' + regex.test(time3));
```

[Probar regex](https://regex101.com/r/D2lf8I/1/)

Answer (score 1):

podrías usar esta:

**HH:MM** 24 horas con 0 inicial opcional.

```js
const regEx = /^([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5]|[0-5][0-9])$/
const time1 = "03:03"
const time2 = "3:3"

console.log('time1 is valid: ' + regEx.test(time1))
console.log('time2 is valid: ' + regEx.test(time2))
```

Comment: Necesito que el caso de la hora 3:3 tambien valide true, osea que en ambos casos sea true

Comment: respuesta actualizada